# External Web Cam Not Recognized

Tags: usb, webcam

I'm having an issue with my external webcam not being recognized on my MacBook Pro. This started suddenly a few days ago. Here are the details.

**HARDWARE/SOFTWARE SPECS:**

- **Webcam:** VicTsing PC317
- **Computer:** MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
- **OS:** Monterrey 12.5 (latest updates installed)

The webcam is plugged into the back of my Dell monitor, which is connected to a powered USB hub, which is plugged into the USB port on my Mac via an adaptor.

**ISSUE AND TROUBLESHOOTING**

- Webcam worked normally until a few days ago.
- Then suddenly it would no longer appear as an option when running Google Meetings or Zoom.
- I tried plugging and unplugging the device and restarting the computer - no luck.
- I tried swapping it with the same webcam that my wife has, to see if it's a hardware issue - her webcam doesn't work either. So this suggests it's not just that my webcam broke suddenly.
- I tried plugging my external microphone into the same port to see if the port was broken, but the microphone works. So this suggests the issue is not due to the USB port on my display, the hub, the cables, or adaptors - since another USB peripheral is working fine from the same port.
- I checked in system report and I DO see the device showing up under the USB section but NOT under the camera section (only built-in Facetime camera appears there). So the device is detected - just not as a camera?

[image: system report]

- I ran `grep -i cam` in Terminal and the camera DOES show up there, listed as "active, busy" (I'm not sure of the significance of this).

[image: terminal]

**NEXT STEPS**

- I'm totally stuck at this stage - it seems like the system is detecting the camera but will no longer show it as an available camera in the applications where I need it.
- Any help or suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried plugging the webcam into the powered hub?

Comment: Hi Agarza, yes I did try that! No luck unfortunately.

Comment: bypass the usb hub and go direct